# Error while setting a run level for a service on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: upstart, chkconfig

I had stopped openvpn from loading at boot by doing this:

`sudo chkconfig  openvpn off`

Now I want it to load at boot up. So I did this:

`sudo chkconfig  openvpn on`

But it fails and the error I get is: the service might have been converted to upstart job.How can I make it load at boot up? I use ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't normally use `chkconfig` on Ubuntu.  It looks like it may have some issues with the newer upstart-based releases.

As a quick fix, use the native `update-rc.d` script to fix the necessary symlinks:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f openvpn remove
sudo update-rc.d -f openvpn defaults
```

That should get you back to a sane state with OpenVPN starting at boot.